# Alternative answer to: "What has one eye but cannot see?"

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I was playing a [riddle app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelxcode.justriddles) and it posed the question:

> What has one eye but cannot see?

There are 12 available tiles of letters (each can only be used once):

<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>

The app is expecting a specific six-letter answer, which is:

> NEEDLE

However, I found an alternative six-letter answer using the available tiles.

What is the alternative answer?

Comment: Well, googling produced the [Eye of the **Noodle**](http://www.allmusic.com/song/eye-of-the-noodle-mt0008525702). (Probably doesn't count, though.)

Comment: I've no eye, dear.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

> **London**.
>
>  The [London Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Eye) or Millennium Wheel is a huge Ferris wheel on the banks of the River Thames.

Comment: I'm not sure "cannot see" fits, considering its notoriously pervasive video surveillance.

Answer (score 6):

`alunna` translates to "pupil" in Italian. "Pupil" has one "i", and is part of a singular "eye", but a pupil, which is the "the dark circular opening in the center of the iris of the eye," cannot actually itself see.

---

Spaghetti Os are a kind of

`noodle`

[image]

However, I can't recall anyone ever saying something like

> "Beauty lies in the eye of the noodle."

or

> "It is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a noodle than for a rich man to enter the kingdom of God."

---

`lunada` translates to "moonshine" in Spanish. "Moonshine" has one "i" and can't see.

---

`adulee` translates to "ring" in French. "Ring" as one "i" and can't see.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> annual

When you consider:

> January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, and December

you understand the "one eye" reference.  In case that's too subtle:

> April is the only month that contains the letter 'i'.